# Cakephp retrieve all controllers as object

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu by adding variables in every controller. Each controller will hold its own links which will be generated in the default template ( default.ctp ). The thing where I am stuck right now is that I have no clue how to get all the controllers **as an object** so I can retrieve the data right away. I do know how to get all the names.

To get the names I used;

```
App::objects('Controller');
```

Beside that, I'm using cakephp 2.5.1 :)

Comment: what do you mean "as an object" ?

Comment: Ah, that might be confused alot. I'm trying to use it as an object again. Like, I want to be able to loop trough all the controllers and call the elements in it. Something like; $cController->menu

Comment: so "as an object" means creating an instance of each controller? In your layout? For all requests? That's imo a pretty bad idea. Alternatively controllers are just a class - you're asking "how can I create an instance of a class" - which should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Any idea how I could build up a menu ( ul, li, a ) which takes each controller and their own links ( thinking about adding an array in a controller which holds the items )? Oh and I need to use it in the view again. ^^"